# Create new data frame columns with return in function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, boolean-expression

In the DataFrame below, I need to check the shop column and add two columns based on shop

| datetime | dtnum | time | tnum | shop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-03-2022 05:25 | 20220302052500 | 05:25:00 | 52500 | PRESS1 |
| 02-03-2022 05:26 | 20220302052600 | 05:26:00 | 52600 | BODY1 |
| 02-03-2022 05:27 | 20220302052700 | 05:27:00 | 52700 | BODY2 |

I tried with below code. that is using same return to make two columns

```
# Apply shop_groupcode
def shop_chk(column):
    if column['shop'] == 'PRESS1' or 'PRESS1_A' or 'E176' or 'E177' or 'E184' or 'E185' or 'E186' or 'E187':
        return 1, 1  # shop code , plant code
    if column['shop'] == 'BODY1' or 'BODY1_A' or 'E179' or 'E180' or 'E181' or 'E208' or \
            'E216' or 'E217' or 'E218' or 'E232':
        return 2, 1 # shop code , plant code
    if column['shop'] == 'BODY2' or 'BODY2_A' or 'E196' or 'E197' or 'E198' or 'E199' or 'E200':
        return 8, 2 # shop code , plant code

df['shop_code', 'plant_code'] = df.apply(shop_chk, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

Code runs without error, two columns are created-  but the column values are all 1

Requirement:
I want to know if there is mistake in code or if there is any efficient method as I have some more shop conditions to check

| datetime | dtnum | time | tnum | shop | shop_code | plant_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-03-2022 05:25 | 20220302052500 | 05:25:00 | 52500 | PRESS1 | 1 | 1 |
| 02-03-2022 05:26 | 20220302052600 | 05:26:00 | 52600 | BODY1 | 2 | 1 |
| 02-03-2022 05:27 | 20220302052700 | 05:27:00 | 52700 | BODY2 | 8 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin` instead of multiple ORs and store those conditions in a list and use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np
conditions = [df['shop'].isin(['PRESS1','PRESS1_A','E176','E177','E184','E185','E186','E187']), 
              df['shop'].isin(['BODY1','BODY1_A','E179','E180','E181','E208','E216','E217','E218','E232']),
              df['shop'].isin(['BODY2','BODY2_A','E196','E197','E198','E199','E200'])
             ]
df['shop_code'] = np.select(conditions, [1, 2, 8])
df['plant_code'] = np.select(conditions, [1, 1, 2])
```

Output:

```
           datetime           dtnum      time   tnum    shop  shop_code  plant_code  
0  02-03-2022 05:25  20220302052500  05:25:00  52500  PRESS1          1           1  
1  02-03-2022 05:26  20220302052600  05:26:00  52600   BODY1          2           1
2  02-03-2022 05:27  20220302052700  05:27:00  52700   BODY2          8           2
```

FYI, the correct syntax is:

```
(column['shop'] == 'PRESS1') or (column['shop'] == 'PRESS1_A') or ...
```

because

```
column['shop'] == 'PRESS1' or 'PRESS1_A' or ...
```

returns either True or 'PRESS1_A' (not a truth-value).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `isin` in combination with providing a list of values:

```py
    if column['shop'].isin(['PRESS1', 'PRESS1_A', 'E176', 'E177', 'E184', 'E185', 'E186', 'E187']):
```

otherwise it will always stick on the first if-statement, because the part after the `or` is always True and hence will always give 1 as a result.

Comment: # Apply shop_groupcode
def shop_chk(column):
    if column['shop'].isin(['PRESS1', 'PRESS1_A', 'E176', 'E177', 'E184', 'E185', 'E186', 'E187']):
        return 1, 1  # shop code , plant code
    if column['shop'].isin(['BODY1', 'BODY1_A', 'E179', 'E180', 'E181', 'E208', 'E216', 'E217','E218', 'E232']):
        return 2, 1  # shop code , plant code
    if column['shop'].isin(['BODY2', 'BODY2_A', 'E196', 'E197', 'E198', 'E199','E200']):
        return 8, 2  # shop code , plant code

df['shop_code', 'plant_code'] = df.apply(shop_chk, axis=1, result_type="expand")

Comment: - tried the above code, i get below error. added bracket in your code for isin closing
  File "<input>", line 3, in shop_chk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Comment: Sorry, fixed a typo...

Comment: thanks. but it dosent work. u can see my code comment